# Access-Denied when uploading to AWS S3 via PHP; but it works via CLI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, permission-denied

## CLI

When I upload a file to the store via command line interface, the upload works without problems:

`aws s3api put-object --bucket <mybucket> --key <myfile> --body <sourcefile>`

## PHP (with [aws-sdk-php](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) )

But attempting the same via PHP, with the same credentials over the same bucket, fails with:

```
NOTICE: PHP message: [ERROR] Error executing "PutObject" on "https://mybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myfile";
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://mybucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myfile` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>F58846A9008809CA</RequestId> 
    <HostId>cDK3h9Lu0TzafGLJ5N2UwSCWnuRxQIYRDfybqlZ8VyX7mm6xJNvLTWq9sa3T0LHk89J4vymgxr4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

---

The bucket is **private** (default) and the user has **full-control**. Running `aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket <mybucket> --key <myfile>` returns:

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "ID": "87ff093h31e67fc19f4108d84a001b2adc06c0ee876c33h77feea701ed6ba"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "ID": "87ff093h31e67fc19f4108d84a001b2adc06c0ee876c33h77feea701ed6ba",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

What might be the causes for being successful in the shell and fail via script?

Comment: Does your bucket have a private and public folder? or is the whole thing assumed public?

Comment: Also what about your bucket policy? have you granted access here?

Comment: No, no public folder allowed. Policy is just for one user with `FULL_CONTROL`. In fact the upload works correctly from CLI.

Comment: A common reason for this is that your `CLI` and `PHP` are using different credentials/roles than you think they are. Could you double check that.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-aws-sdk/

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

Comment: @ShantanuGupta The first link helped me confirm what @Marcin said. `aws sts get-caller-identity` returned a different UserID from the `getCallerIdentity` from the PHP sdk.